# Why CPU Freq Crosses Hardware Limits and Policy Limits, and System Heat Up after Hybrid Sleep, in Debian 12 (Testing-Weekly)?

Tags: linux, debian, cpu-frequency, temperature, fan

In **Debian 12** (bookworm: testing-weekly):

Installed **`auto-cpufreq`** and `thermald`, with `auto-cpufreq.conf` while on **charger**:

```
governor = performance    
scaling_max_freq = 1900000    
turbo = auto
```

Thought it is conflicting with some other tools. So, **removed** all other tools: `tlp cpufreq cpupower acpi acpid acpi-support linux-cpupower cpufrequtils cpulimit`

Hardware (Apple: amd64, 16 GB RAM, 8 CPU) limit: 800 MHz - 2800 MHz

After reboot, everything (CPU Freq, Temperature, etc.) stays within limits, as set in auto-cpufreq.conf.

But, **AFTER Hybrid Sleep**, things go out of control: (CPU Freq near 3800 MHz, Temp 90℃, Fan 4600 RPM).

What am I missing?

Comment: `bookworm: testing-weekly` have you tried `bookworm: released a week ago`?

Comment: @Jaromanda X
**I did**. But, NO change. I am not sure whether it has some thing to do with some of the default packages that I removed were **bundled with debian...**